# What's the difference between cflags and ldflags in gyp

Tags: chromium, gyp

I'm looking into gyp & gypi files in chromium.  What's the role of `cflags` and `ldflags`?

What does below code mean?

```
 'cflags': '<!@(<(pkg-config) --cflags gstreamer-0.10)',

 'ldflags': '<!@(<(pkg-config) --libs-only-L --libs-only-other gstreamer-0.10)',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to study about makefile. and found :

```
cflags - this is used to set environment variable and configuration option for C compiler
ldflag - flag for ld linker
```

and there are other flags as below :

```
ARFLAGS - for ar achiver
ASFLAGS - for as assembler
CXXFLAGS - for c++ compiler
COFLAGS - for co utility
CPPFLAGS - for C preprocessor
FFLAGS - for Fortran compiler
LFLAGS - for lex
PFLAGS - for Pascal compiler
YFLAGS - for yacc
```